# ElasticSearch, inconsistency between size and count/search?

Tags: elasticsearch, search-guard

I created and indexed some docs in ES via curl POST.

When I GET *'myhost/_cat/indices?v'*, I can see my index and count ~95000 and store.size ~20mb.

But when I GET *'myhost/myindex/_count*' it returns 0. Or I GET *'myhost/myindex/_search?q=*:*'* then it does not hit anything.

I use SearchGuard but there are not any error or permission warns etc.

What can be problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try via kibana?

Comment: I never used kibana.

Comment: can you share your command?

Comment: For loading == >> curl --cacert xxx.pem -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxx" -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --request POST 'https://myhost/myindex/_doc?pretty ' -d '{"name" : "JACK"}'

Comment: For query ==>>  curl --cacert xxx.pem -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxx" -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --request GET 'https://myhost/myindex/_search?q=*:* '

Comment: I can see ~95000 in column docs.count in /_cat/indices?v

Comment: Are you using nested documents? Usually, the difference between `_cat/indices` and `_count` is due to nested documents being counted in `_cat/indices`, but that wouldn't explain why you get no documents at all. How do your documents look like?